# How get id from selected row on datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a doubt,

How can i get an specific id from a current cell?
I'm doing a fileuploader in a datagridview per ROW,
So when I clic on the fileUploader and i press Upload (To upload the file),
I need to get an specific id from the current row when I clic "Upload".

[ID To get whene you press "Upload"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQNZe.png)

Comment: Add `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>'` to the button.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev mm, i'm new on this, i already put the command on my upload button, so now what i do?

Comment: Add `button_Command` or `gridview_ItemCommand` handler where you can receive `e.CommandArgument`.

Comment: Try using datakeynames  check this link   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23833/DataKeyNames

Answer (score 0):

You could use a command button in ASP.NET and pass through the ID to the code behind like this - `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'`.One thing to note though is that the command button needs to implement the `OnCommand` event not `OnClick`.

Below is a simple example to help you get started.

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var f1 = new FileData { ID = 1 };
        var f2 = new FileData { ID = 2 };

        GridView1.DataSource = new List<FileData> { f1, f2 };
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void bntFileUpload_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "Upload")
    {
        int id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        lblOutput.Text = String.Format("You clicked on ID - {0}", id);
    }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="bntFileUpload" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' OnCommand="bntFileUpload_Command" CommandName="Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```